# What is the size difference between Convolutional Neural Networks that take as input an RGB vs. monochrome image?

Tags: conv-neural-network, rgb, monochrome

VGG 16 Convolutional Neural Network takes an RGB image as an input, with 2^24 possible pixel values. It has 138,357,544 parameters.

[image]

Consider a minimum size version of this network for grayscale images, i.e. 256 possible pixel values, with all redundancies removed. Feeding (r, g, b) pixels with r=g=b to the original network should be used as an equivalency test. How many parameters this grayscale network would have? Would performance scale linearly with decreased number of parameters?